# Precision matrix and conditional uncorrelatedness

Tags: covariance-matrix, partial-correlation, precision-matrix

Let $\mathbf{u}_t = (u_{1t},u_{2t},\ldots,u_{pt})^{\prime}$ be a $p \times 1$ (stationary) random vector, and let $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{u}$ be the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{u}_t$. Further, denote the precision matrix $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_u=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_u^{-1}$.

Then there is an interesting reslut linking the precision matrix $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_u$ and the **conditional** uncorrelatedness which may be stated in the following paragraph:

``the sparsity of $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_u=\left(\omega_{u, i j}\right)_{p \times p}$ encodes the conditional uncorrelatedness (or conditional independence in the case of Gaussian distribution) relationships between all variables in the $p$ dimensional vector $\mathbf{u}_t$. More specifically, for $p$ nodes $U_1, \ldots, U_p$, each corresponding to one element of $\mathbf{u}_t, U_i$ and $U_j$ are connected if and only if $\omega_{u, i j} \neq 0$, meaning that $u_{i t}$ and $u_{j t}$ are uncorrelated conditioning on all the other dimensions $\left\{u_{k t}\right\}_{k \neq i, j}$.''

My question is: is there a proof for this interesting result? I just verifed this when $p=3$, but how about in a more general case?

Comment: The general case works like $p=3$, if you write the calculation for a partitioned matrix with variables $3,4,...,p$ as one block. Equivalently, if you write down the formula for the conditional distribution of $u_i$ given $u_{-i}$, the dependence on $u_j$ is proportional to $\omega_{ij}$. Someone needs to actually write down the formulas to give a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Sounds good.